# How deleting image.bmp with win32 api?

Tags: win32-process

I created a window with three selection BUTTONS,three descriptive LABEL and a background image.bmp. obtained with
WM_PAINT,
BeginPaint()
....
EndPaint()
and an .rc file where there are data to load image.bmp.
I made it so that, by clicking either on one of the BUTTONS of choice I make the BUTTONS and the LABEL disappear (as I want)  but I can't get the image.bmp to disappear.

I kindly ask to you if you can give me some indication to make the image.bmp disappear.

Thanks MarioAngelo